# Get the name of a branch in the Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a project using multiple repositories:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: one
    type: git
    name: repo/one
    ref: release
  - repository: two
    type: git
    name: repo/two
    ref: develop
  - repository: three
    type: git
    name: repo/three
    ref: master
```

How do I get the environment variables for each of these repositories in subsequent steps? For example, I'm interested in the variable $(Build.BuildNumber). Now I only get the variable for the branch from which the yaml project itself is launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `repository` keyword in `resources` lets you specify external repositories.

When you check out multiple repositories, some details about the self repository are available as [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

When you use multi-repo triggers, some of those variables have information about the triggering repository instead. Details about all of the repositories consumed by the job are available as a [template context object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#context) called resources.repositories

To get the environment variables for each of these repositories you need to define variable:

Example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: other
    type: git
    name: MyProject/OtherTools

variables:
  tools.ref: $[ resources.repositories['other'].ref ]

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: other
- bash: |
    echo "Tools version: $(tools.ref)"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-details

Comment: I tried this option and I get an empty variable $TOOLS_REF
Also, I can't see how to get the branch name.

Comment: You can consume varibles in bash like echo "Tools version: $(tools.ref)"

Comment: It seems nowhere to be found what variables are exposed. How can one find that out?